# проблема бесконечного цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется .txt файл в котором размещено:

```
login:"user";password:"qwerty";
login:"admin";password:"admin";
```

В цикле for образуется бесконечный цикл.Как исправить это?
Суть кода в том чтобы проверить правильность введённых данных.

```
name = input("введите ваш логин: ")
file = open("F:\programme\logins.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
a = file.read()
c = a.find(";")-2
for line in file:
    if name in line[5:c]:
        print("Хорошо")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код с моими комментариями:

```
name = input("введите ваш логин: ")

file = open(                    # здесь, лучше было использовать оператор with
    "logins.txt",
    "r",                        # в функции open() по умолчанию режим открытия файла - 'rt'(ReadText),
                                # так что аргумент 'r' можно не указывать

    encoding='utf-8'            # 'utf-8' тоже указывать не обязательно
)

a = file.read()                 # вы прочитали весь файл

                                # дальше происходит что-то странное

c = a.find(";")-2               # вы находите букву "r"

for line in file:               # тут вам следовало вместо file написать
                                # file.readlines() и тогда всё было бы немного лучше
    if name in line[5:c]:
        print("Хорошо") 
                                # вы не закрыли файл
```

Ваш же код, который я немного подправил:

```
name = input("введите ваш логин: ")

with open('logins.txt') as f:
    a = f.readlines()

    for line in a:
        c = line.find(';')
        if name in line[5:c]:
            print('Хорошо')
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно так-себе авторизация )). Но эту задачу можно решить так, на мой взгляд:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    name = input("введите ваш логин: ")

    s = [_.replace('\n', '') for _ in open('file.csv', 'r').readlines()]

    creds = {}
    for line in s:
        cr = line.split(';')
        creds[cr[0].split(':')[1]] = cr[1].split(':')[1]

    if name in creds:
        passwd = input('Введите пароль: ')
        if passwd == creds[name]:
            print('Авторизация прошла успешно')
        else:
            print('Что-то пошло не так')
    else:
        print('Пользователь с именем {} не зарегистрирован'.format(name))
```

Можно заменить:

```
creds = {}
for line in s:
      cr = line.split(';')
      creds[cr[0].split(':')[1]] = cr[1].split(':')[1]
```

На

```
creds = {_[0].split(':')[1]: _[1].split(':')[1] for _ in [line.split(';') for line in s]}
```

Answer (score 0):

я немного изменил содержимое `logins.txt`

```
login:user;password:qwerty;
login:admin;password:admin;
```

**main.py**

```
with open("logins.txt", "r") as f:
    myList = [ it for line in f  for it in line.strip().split(';') if it]

name = input("Bведите ваш логин: ")
loginName = "login:{}".format(name)
if loginName in myList:
    print("Хорошо!")
else: 
    print("Что-то пошло не так?")
```

---

Update: **main.py**

```
with open("logins.txt", "r") as f:
    myList = [ line.strip() for line in f  if line]
print( myList )   

login = input("Bведите ваш login: ")
password = input("Bведите ваш password: ")

loginPassword = "login:{};password:{};".format(login, password)
if loginPassword in myList:
    print("Хорошо!")
else: 
    print("Что-то пошло не так?")
```